# Error getting connection with MySQL connector

Tags: java, mysql

The error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

And here is my code.

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", "root");
        connectionProps.put("password", "pass");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" , connectionProps);
        System.out.println("Connected to database");
        return conn;

    }
```

Comment: What does the documentation state about drivers? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you import it? `import java.sql.*;` try putting in the top of class.
Also put this `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` in before the `DriverManager.getconnection` for class to identify the driver.

Comment: Oh thank you , sir. I added Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); before getConnection method and it works . Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your driver before getting connection (if it's already registered, nothing will be done):

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        Connection conn;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", "root");
        connectionProps.put("password", "pass");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl , connectionProps);
        System.out.println("Connected to database");
        return conn;
}
```